# Getting out of range while splitting values from list in python

Tags: python

I've list of string like below:

```
12345,abcd,03/03/2013,23,,32,EURRIE-373HFJ-DJDMKD|838383,ldof,09/02/2017,23,,32,DJJFJF-DJFH83-JDUEJD|939393,uejs,08/07/2016,23,,32,JDJFJF-UEJDKD-LEPEKD|
```

My code:

```
content = "12345,abcd,03/03/2013,23,,32,EURRIE-373HFJ-DJDMKD|838383,ldof,09/02/2017,23,,32,DJJFJF-DJFH83-JDUEJD|939393,uejs,08/07/2016,23,,32,JDJFJF-UEJDKD-LEPEKD|"

result = [content.split(',')[2] for content in content.split('|')]
for v in result[:-1]:
  print v
```

I want to print all second index element which is

```
03/03/2013
09/02/2017
08/07/2016
```

But I'm getting out of range error, what i'm doing wrong here.

Can someone help to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re`:

```
import re

content = "12345,abcd,03/03/2013,23,,32,EURRIE-373HFJ-DJDMKD|838383,ldof,09/02/2017,23,,32,DJJFJF-DJFH83-JDUEJD|939393,uejs,08/07/2016,23,,32,JDJFJF-UEJDKD-LEPEKD|"
result = re.findall('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', content)
```

Result:

```
for date in result:
    print date

# 03/03/2013
# 09/02/2017
# 08/07/2016
```

---

Also you can fix your code by filtering out empty elements after the 1st split:

```
result = [content.split(',')[2] for content in content.split('|') if len(content)]
```

Result:

```
for v in result:
    print v

# 03/03/2013
# 09/02/2017
# 08/07/2016
```

Answer (score 2):

When I tested your code, I found that content.split('|') was generating an empty last element that was responsible for the index error after the split. So I changed it for:

```
[content.split(',')[2] for content in content.split('|')[:-1]]
```

and got:

```
['03/03/2013', '09/02/2017', '08/07/2016']
```

Does that solve the issue for you?